# How can I change the font size of headings using mwcls?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, mwcls

I use `\documentclass mwrep`.
I want to change:
`chapter` to have font size 14pt bold
`section` to have font size 13pt bold
`subsection` to have font size 12pt bold italic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Polish isn't very good, (in fact non-existent) but from the documentation of `mwrep` I was able to figure out the following:

```
\SetSectionFormatting{section} {24pt plus5pt minus2pt}
{\FormatHangHeading{\fontsize{13}{13}\selectfont}} {10pt plus3pt}
\SetSectionFormatting{subsection} {24pt plus5pt minus2pt}
{\FormatHangHeading{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\itshape}} {10pt plus3pt}
\SetSectionFormatting{chapter} {24pt plus5pt minus2pt}
{\FormatHangHeading{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont}} {10pt plus3pt}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check MWCLS Podręcznik użytkownika (`texdoc mwcls`). There are `\SetSectionFormatting`, `\FormatChapterHeading` and similar macros for defining look of chapter, section or subsection headers. You can use there e.g. `\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont` for 14pt, etc.